# Webcam Web Server in Dot Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, webserver, webcam

I've been searching for a couple days to find an example project that allows one to build a "web server" that simply streams a webcam video to anyone who connects to it.  Sounds simple enough.   There are apps out there for this but I want to embed this functionality into a windows form application I am working on.

So again, I just want to build a project that acts as a HTTP host (web server) and when you connect to it, it will serve webcam video.   Of course you'd like to be able to server more than one person at a time.

Can anyone point me to such a project/example?

Comment: Off-site resource requests and tutorials are off topic here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish you can install the NuGet package [NequeoFFmpeg](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NequeoFFmpeg/), this is a C++/CLI wrapper of some FFmpeg tools. One thing you can do is use this wrapper to get WebCam data through the FFmpeg binaries. You can get my pre-built FFmpeg binaries from [FFmpeg](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-mLEsywAIXBbk1OWjdKRWp0TFU) please use version 2016_01_15.

Code sample:

```
    private void Capture()
    {
        Nequeo.Media.FFmpeg.MediaDemux demux = new Nequeo.Media.FFmpeg.MediaDemux();
        demux.OpenDevice("video=Integrated Webcam", true, false);

        // create instance of video writer
        Nequeo.Media.FFmpeg.VideoFileWriter writer = new Nequeo.Media.FFmpeg.VideoFileWriter();
        writer.Open(@"C:\Temp\Misc\ffmpeg_screen_capture_video.avi", demux.Width, demux.Height, demux.FrameRate, Nequeo.Media.FFmpeg.VideoCodec.MPEG4);

        byte[] sound = null;
        Bitmap[] image = null;

        List<Bitmap> video = new List<Bitmap>();
        long audioPos = 0;
        long videoPos = 0;

        int captureCount = 0;
        int captureNumber = 500;

        while ((demux.ReadFrame(out sound, out image, out audioPos, out videoPos) > 0) && captureCount < captureNumber)
        {
            if (image != null && image.Length > 0)
            {
                captureCount++;

                for (int i = 0; i < image.Length; i++)
                {
                    writer.WriteVideoFrame(image[i]);
                    image[i].Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        writer.Close();
        demux.Close();
    }
```

Set the video capture device name, In the sample above I write to a file, but you can just write the Bitmap to a stream. You could compress the bitmap and then write to a stream. You could change the Bitmap to Jpeg and then send to a stream.

FFmpeg can stream live WebCam video see: [StreamingGuide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide)

Comment: This looks promising.   What about the HTTP server portion?  if I write to a stream that stream has to be sent to multiple HTML viewers.   Is there a sample of this?   It's been a long time since I wrote a protocol server.

Comment: I have added a UDP server sample, with UDP desktop client. HTTP server can be adapted from the UDP server, as well as a HTTP desktop client. As far as a HTML in a web browser this is much more work.

Comment: Well I poked at this for a while in Visual Studio 15 and could not get it running.  I got all the packages installed and ffmpeg and got the app to start and the light on the webcam came on.  But I could not connect to the port and eventually got an error.   Looks good and I was excited but was somewhat disappointed.  I am sure I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Sample [code](https://github.com/nequeo/misc/blob/master/csharp/UDPWebCamServerClient.zip) of UDP client and server, please update all NuGet packages.

Comment: I actually tried the code prior to your UDP example.  It is unchanged except for the name of the webcam (I have a logitech one).  The biggest issue to get it to actually comp[ile and go was realizing this is an x86 .net 4.6 setup.  Anyhow, unmodified.  I didn't try the udp version.  Is that better do you think?

Comment: I have added all the answers in one [solution](https://github.com/nequeo/misc/blob/master/csharp/UDPWebCamServerClient.zip), Capture to file, UDP client server and WebSocket server and HTML WebSocket client. All projects capture data, please note update all NuGet packages. Because FFmpeg binaries are x64 or x86 builds, and the FFmpeg wrapper is C++/CLI also x64 or x86, the solution must be build in x64 or x86. Thus the solution must reference x64 or x86 FFmpeg libs.

Comment: I may be able to figure this out on my own but what if I want a preview of what the webcam is broadcasting on the server? Where would I grab the frames and put them into, I assume, a picture box?

Comment: Also, is there any chance we could do without Nequeo?  At least for the listener?   I need to be able to use this as a web server as well (I know, a big wish).

Comment: No, I will not go through MB of code to change just one thing.

Comment: Lol it's fine.  I did it

Answer (score 3):

For all that are interested in streaming WebCam data to web browsers the code below uses WebSockets, To use the sample get the NuGet package [NequeoWebSockets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NequeoWebSockets/) as well as [NequeoFFmpeg](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NequeoFFmpeg/)

Starting the WebSocket server:

```
TestServer.WebcamWebSocketServer wsServer = new WebcamWebSocketServer();
wsServer.UriList = new string[] { "http://localhost:2012/" };
wsServer.Start();
```

WebCam WebSocket server code: Adapt your code to the sample.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace TestServer
{
public class WebcamWebSocketServer : Nequeo.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketServer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public WebcamWebSocketServer()
    {
        OnServerInitialise();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uriList"></param>
    public WebcamWebSocketServer(string[] uriList)
        : base(uriList)
    {
        OnServerInitialise();
    }

    int _clientCount = 0;
    private int READ_BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
    private bool _stopCapture = false;
    private Nequeo.Media.FFmpeg.MediaDemux _demuxHttp = null;
    ConcurrentDictionary<System.Net.WebSockets.HttpListenerWebSocketContext, WebSocket> _clients = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private void OnServerInitialise()
    {
        base.Timeout = 60;
        base.HeaderTimeout = 30000;
        base.RequestTimeout = 30000;
        base.ResponseTimeout = 30000;
        base.Name = "Nequeo Web Socket Server";
        base.ServiceName = "WebSocketServer";
        base.OnWebSocketContext += WebSocketServer_OnWebSocketContext;

        _demuxHttp = new Nequeo.Media.FFmpeg.MediaDemux();

        // Open the web cam device.
        _demuxHttp.OpenDevice("video=Integrated Webcam", true, false);
        _clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<HttpListenerWebSocketContext, WebSocket>();

        // Start capture.
        CaptureAndSend();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    private void WebSocketServer_OnWebSocketContext(object sender, System.Net.WebSockets.HttpListenerWebSocketContext context)
    {
        OnWebcamWebSocketContext(context);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    private async void OnWebcamWebSocketContext(System.Net.WebSockets.HttpListenerWebSocketContext context)
    {
        WebSocket webSocket = null;

        try
        {
            // Get the current web socket.
            webSocket = context.WebSocket;

            CancellationTokenSource receiveCancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];

            // While the WebSocket connection remains open run a 
            // simple loop that receives data and sends it back.
            while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                // Receive the next set of data.
                ArraySegment<byte> arrayBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer);
                WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(arrayBuffer, receiveCancelToken.Token);

                // If the connection has been closed.
                if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Add the client 
                    _clients.GetOrAdd(context, webSocket);
                }
            }

            // Cancel the receive request.
            if (webSocket.State != WebSocketState.Open)
                receiveCancelToken.Cancel();
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            // Clean up by disposing the WebSocket.
            if (webSocket != null)
                webSocket.Dispose();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private async void CaptureAndSend()
    {
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            byte[] sound = null;
            Bitmap[] image = null;

            long audioPos = 0;
            long videoPos = 0;

            int count = 0;
            KeyValuePair<HttpListenerWebSocketContext, WebSocket>[] clientCol = null;

            // Most of the time one image at a time.
            MemoryStream[] imageStream = new MemoryStream[10];
            int imageStreamCount = 0;

            // Within this loop you can place a check if there are any clients
            // connected, and if none then stop capturing until some are connected.
            while ((_demuxHttp.ReadFrame(out sound, out image, out audioPos, out videoPos) > 0) && !_stopCapture)
            {
                imageStreamCount = 0;
                count = _clients.Count;

                // If count has changed.
                if (_clientCount != count)
                {
                    // Get the collection of all clients.
                    _clientCount = count;
                    clientCol = _clients.ToArray();
                }

                // Has an image been captured.
                if (image != null && image.Length > 0)
                {
                    // Get all clients and send.
                    if (clientCol != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < image.Length; i++)
                        {
                            // Create a memory stream for each image.
                            imageStream[i] = new MemoryStream();
                            imageStreamCount++;

                            // Save the image to the stream.
                            image[i].Save(imageStream[i], System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                            // Cleanup.
                            image[i].Dispose();
                        }

                        // For each client.
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<HttpListenerWebSocketContext, WebSocket> client in clientCol)
                        {
                            // For each image captured.
                            for (int i = 0; i < imageStreamCount; i++)
                            {
                                // data to send.
                                byte[] result = imageStream[0].GetBuffer();

                                string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(result);
                                byte[] base64Bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(base64);

                                try
                                {
                                    // Send a message back to the client indicating that
                                    // the message was recivied and was sent.
                                    await client.Value.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(base64Bytes),
                                        WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                                }
                                catch { }

                                imageStream[i].Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            }
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < imageStreamCount; i++)
                            // Cleanup.
                            imageStream[i].Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
 }
 }
```

The code for a single HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var noSupportMessage = "Your browser cannot support WebSocket!";
        var ws;

        function appendMessage(message) {
            $('body').append(message);
        }

        function connectSocketServer() {
            var support = "MozWebSocket" in window ? 'MozWebSocket' : ("WebSocket" in window ? 'WebSocket' : null);

            if (support == null) {
                appendMessage("* " + noSupportMessage + "<br/>");
                return;
            }

            appendMessage("* Connecting to server ..<br/>");
            // create a new websocket and connect
            ws = new window[support]('ws://localhost:2012/');
            ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

            // when data is comming from the server, this metod is called
            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                if (evt.data) {
                    drawImage(evt.data);
                }
            };

            // when the connection is established, this method is called
            ws.onopen = function () {
                appendMessage('* Connection open<br/>');
                $('#messageInput').attr("disabled", "");
                $('#sendButton').attr("disabled", "");
                $('#connectButton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#disconnectButton').attr("disabled", "");
            };

            // when the connection is closed, this method is called
            ws.onclose = function () {
                appendMessage('* Connection closed<br/>');
                $('#messageInput').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#sendButton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#connectButton').attr("disabled", "");
                $('#disconnectButton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        }

        function sendMessage() {
            if (ws) {
                var messageBox = document.getElementById('messageInput');
                ws.send(messageBox.value);
                messageBox.value = "";
            }
        }

        function disconnectWebSocket() {
            if (ws) {
                ws.close();
            }
        }

        function connectWebSocket() {
            connectSocketServer();
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            $('#messageInput').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#sendButton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#disconnectButton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }

        function drawImage(data)
        {
            $("#image").attr('src', 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + data);
        }

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <input type="button" id="connectButton" value="Connect" onclick="connectWebSocket()" />
     <input type="button" id="disconnectButton" value="Disconnect" onclick="disconnectWebSocket()" />
     <input type="text" id="messageInput" />
     <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Load Remote Image" onclick="sendMessage()" /> <br />
     <img id="image" src="" width="320" height="240" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: D., Did you post a complete solution?  I thought you did but now I cannot seem to find it.  I like the style of your code and would love to try it but I cannot get it to go in VS2015.  At least not easily.  Thanks

Comment: Posted all three projects in one [solution](https://github.com/nequeo/misc/blob/master/csharp/UDPWebCamServerClient.zip) with some instruction on this page on Jan 27

Comment: Thanks D.   I grabbed it and will play with it over the weekend.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a simple UDP server to broadcast captured images from the WebCam, please note there is no protocol involved in sending the captured images, such as RTSP. After capturing the image from the WebCam it sends that image as is. On the client when the image is received you must render that image as you wish.

This server should not be used for more than about 100 clients, if you need something more robust, you will need to find some other alternative.

For the server part you will need to install NuGet package [NequeoNetServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NequeoNetServer/) as well as [NequeoFFmpeg](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NequeoFFmpeg/):

```
    int _clientCount = 0;
    bool _stopCapture = false;
    Nequeo.Net.UdpSingleServer _udpsingle = null;
    Nequeo.Media.FFmpeg.MediaDemux _demux = null;
    ConcurrentDictionary<IPEndPoint, Nequeo.Net.Sockets.IUdpSingleServer> _clients = null;

    private void StartServer()
    {
        // Create the server endpoint.
        Nequeo.Net.Sockets.MultiEndpointModel[] model = new Nequeo.Net.Sockets.MultiEndpointModel[]
            {
                // None secure.
                new Nequeo.Net.Sockets.MultiEndpointModel()
                {
                    Port = 514,
                    Addresses = new System.Net.IPAddress[]
                    {
                        System.Net.IPAddress.IPv6Any,
                        System.Net.IPAddress.Any
                    }
                },
            };

        if (_udpsingle == null)
        {
            // Create the UDP server.
            _udpsingle = new Nequeo.Net.UdpSingleServer(model);
            _udpsingle.OnContext += UDP_Single;
        }

        // Create the client collection.
        _clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<IPEndPoint, Nequeo.Net.Sockets.IUdpSingleServer>();
        _demux = new Nequeo.Media.FFmpeg.MediaDemux();

        // Start the server.
        _udpsingle.Start();

        _clientCount = 0;
        _stopCapture = false;

        // Start the capture process.
        CaptureAndSend();
    }
```

Stop the server:

```
    private void StopServer()
    {
        _clientCount = 0;
        _stopCapture = true;

        if (_udpsingle != null)
        {
            _udpsingle.Stop();
            _udpsingle.Dispose();
        }
        _udpsingle = null;

        if (_demux != null)
            _demux.Close();

        _demux = null;
    }
```

Client sent message:

```
    private void UDP_Single(object sender, Nequeo.Net.Sockets.IUdpSingleServer server, byte[] data, IPEndPoint endpoint)
    {
        string request = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);

        if (request.ToLower().Contains("connect"))
            // Add the new client.
            _clients.GetOrAdd(endpoint, server);

        if (request.ToLower().Contains("disconnect"))
        {
            Nequeo.Net.Sockets.IUdpSingleServer removedServer = null;

            // Remove the existing client.
            _clients.TryRemove(endpoint, out removedServer);
        }
    }
```

The capture: from the demux you can get the `_demux.Width`, `_demux.Height` and `_demux.FrameRate` of the capture device.

```
    private async void CaptureAndSend()
    {
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (_demux != null)
            {
                // Open the web cam device.
                _demux.OpenDevice("video=Integrated Webcam", true, false);

                byte[] sound = null;
                Bitmap[] image = null;

                long audioPos = 0;
                long videoPos = 0;

                int count = 0;
                KeyValuePair<IPEndPoint, Nequeo.Net.Sockets.IUdpSingleServer>[] clientCol = null;

                // Most of the time one image at a time.
                MemoryStream[] imageStream = new MemoryStream[10];
                int imageStreamCount = 0;

                // Within this loop you can place a check if there are any clients
                // connected, and if none then stop capturing until some are connected.
                while ((_demux.ReadFrame(out sound, out image, out audioPos, out videoPos) > 0) && !_stopCapture)
                {
                    imageStreamCount = 0;
                    count = _clients.Count;

                    // If count has changed.
                    if (_clientCount != count)
                    {
                        // Get the collection of all clients.
                        _clientCount = count;
                        clientCol = _clients.ToArray();
                    }

                    // Has an image been captured.
                    if (image != null && image.Length > 0)
                    {
                        // Get all clients and send.
                        if (clientCol != null)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < image.Length; i++)
                            {
                                // Create a memory stream for each image.
                                imageStream[i] = new MemoryStream();
                                imageStreamCount++;

                                // Save the image to the stream.
                                image[i].Save(imageStream[i], System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                                // Cleanup.
                                image[i].Dispose();
                            }

                            // For each client.
                            foreach (KeyValuePair<IPEndPoint, Nequeo.Net.Sockets.IUdpSingleServer> client in clientCol)
                            {
                                // For each image captured.
                                for (int i = 0; i < imageStreamCount; i++)
                                {
                                    // Send the image to this client.
                                    client.Value.SendTo(imageStream[i].ToArray(), client.Key);
                                    imageStream[i].Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                }
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < imageStreamCount; i++)
                                // Cleanup.
                                imageStream[i].Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

On the client side as indicated above the data received is the captured images and you need to render the image and all subsequent images. You could send to the client from the server the `Width`, `Height`, and `FrameRate` of the captured images, which could be used to render each image received.

The client code: UDP client state container

```
public class UdpState
{
    public UdpClient u { get; set; }
    public IPEndPoint e { get; set; }
}
```

The client code: the client code should include some data buffer, so you can receive and render images without any dropped frames.

```
    private void Connect()
    {
        pictureBox1.ClientSize = new Size(320, 240);

        // Create the client.
        IPEndPoint ee = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 541);
        UdpClient u = new UdpClient(ee);

        // Create the state.
        UdpState s = new UdpState();
        s.e = ee;
        s.u = u;

        // Connect to the server.
        IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 514);
        u.Connect("localhost", 514);

        // Start the begin receive callback.
        u.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), s);

        // Send a connect request.
        byte[] connect = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("connect");
        u.Send(connect, connect.Length);
    }
```

In the receive callback you can render the WebCam image to a picture box.

```
    public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Get the client.
        UdpClient u = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).u;
        IPEndPoint e = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e;

        // Get the image.
        Byte[] receiveBytes = u.EndReceive(ar, ref e);

        // Load the image into a stream.
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(receiveBytes);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);

        // Add the image to the picture box.
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.Image = image;

        stream.Dispose();

        // Start a new receive request.
        u.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), (UdpState)(ar.AsyncState));
    }
```

NOTE: I created a UDP sample, but you can create a HTTP TCP sample using the same approach, the NuGet package [NequeoNetServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NequeoNetServer/) contains a custom HTTP server you can adapt to serve any HTTP request.

```
private void StartCustomHttpServer()
{
     Nequeo.Net.CustomServer c = new Nequeo.Net.CustomServer(typeof(http), 30);
     c.Start();
}
```

The custom HTTP server class:

```
internal class http : Nequeo.Net.Http.CustomContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// On new client Http context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The client Http context.</param>
    protected override void OnHttpContext(Nequeo.Net.Http.HttpContext context)
    {
        // Get the headers from the stream and assign the request data.
        bool headersExist = Nequeo.Net.Http.Utility.SetRequestHeaders(context, 30000, 10000);

        context.HttpResponse.ContentLength = 5;
        context.HttpResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.HttpResponse.StatusCode = 200;
        context.HttpResponse.StatusDescription = "OK";
        context.HttpResponse.WriteHttpHeaders();
        context.HttpResponse.Write("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks D., going to play with it this weekend.   100 clients should be fine.  I am not expecting more than a dozen at any one time.

Comment: I have added a HTML web browser WebSocket sample.